# JAVAFX: Set cursor CURSOR.WAIT while running PauseTransition

Tags: java, javafx

How to set the cursor to CURSOR.WAIT while running PauseTransition?

```
public void dashboard() {
    PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
    wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {
        GuiManager.getInstance().showView(new DashboardView());
    });
    wait.play();
}
```

Comment: What is your main panel? is it that new DashboardView()?

Comment: yes, thats it..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a PauseTransition, use a [Timeline](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html):

```
Animation wait = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
        new KeyValue(someNode.cursorProperty(), Cursor.WAIT)),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
        new KeyValue(someNode.cursorProperty(), null)));

wait.setOnFinished(e -> 
    GuiManager.getInstance().showView(new DashboardView()));

wait.play();
```